# How to create a stylefunction considering different geometries for different styles in OL?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to style a layer that contains MultiPolygon geometries as well as Polygon geometries (using OL 4.1.1). All geometries should be coloured. The text lables on the other hand should just be set for the largest polygon (in case of MultiPolygon). How do I consider different geometries for different styles (e.g. `ol.style.Fill` and `ol.style.Text`) in the same style container (`ol.style.Style`)?

Some code for illustration:

```
var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
    return new ol.style.Style({
        geometry: selectLargestPolygon(feature), // the single Polygon or largest in case of MultiPolygon
        // geometry does not need to be set in case of fill...
        fill: new ol.style.Fill(...), // should always consider the whole geometry! (not just the largest Polygon in case of MultiPolygon!)
        text: new ol.style.Text(...) // should just consider the largest polygon
    });
};
```

Comment: See a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306548/how-to-show-one-label-per-multi-polygon-in-open-layers-3), which contains the answer you might be looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The solution by @pavlos solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks *@Alexandre Dubé* for pointing at this [solution by *@pavlos* on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37316821). The solution is to create two styles and return both in the stylefunction. For my example:

```
// style for geometry dependent text
var getGeometryDependentTextStyle = function(feature){
    return new ol.style.Style({
        geometry: selectLargestPolygon(feature), // use largest polygon only
        text: new ol.style.Text(...)
    });
}

// geometry independent fill style
var universalStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill(...) // colour all geometries
});

// combined style
var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
    return [universalStyle, getGeometryDependentTextStyle(feature)];
};
```